# Implementing a AVL tree in C

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I am attempting to implement an array into a BST, after printing out the BST(pre-order), I am balancing it out (AVL tree with pre-order output).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    int height;
};

struct node *new_node(int data) {
    struct node *nn = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    nn->data = data;
    nn->left = NULL;
    nn->right = NULL;
    nn->height = 1;

    return nn;
}

struct node *insert(struct node *root, int data) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return new_node(data);
    else {
        if (data < root->data)
            root->left = insert(root->left, data);
        if (data > root->data)
            root->right = insert(root->right, data);
        return root;
    }
}

void pre_order(struct node *root) {
    if (root != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", root->data);
        pre_order(root->left);
        pre_order(root->right);
    }
}

int height(struct node *n) { 
    if (n == NULL) 
        return 0; 
    return n->height; 
} 

int max(int a, int b) 
{ 
    return (a > b) ? a : b; 
} 

struct node *rightRotate(struct node *y) 
{ 
    struct node *x = y->left; 
    struct node *T2 = x->right; 

    x->right = y; 
    y->left = T2; 

    y->height = max(height(y->left), height(y->right)) + 1; 
    x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right)) + 1; 

    return x; 
} 

struct node *leftRotate(struct node *x) { 
    struct node *y = x->right; 
    struct node *T2 = y->left; 

    y->left = x; 
    x->right = T2; 

    x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right)) + 1; 
    y->height = max(height(y->left), height(y->right)) + 1; 

    return y; 
} 

int getBalance(struct node *n) { 
    if (n == NULL) 
        return 0; 
    return height(n->left) - height(n->right); 
} 

struct node *AVLbalance(struct node *root, int data) 
{ 
    root->height = 1 + max(height(root->left), 
                           height(root->right)); 

    int balance = getBalance(root); 

    // Left Left Case 
    if (balance > 1 && data < root->left->data) 
        return rightRotate(root); 

    // Right Right Case 
    if (balance < -1 && data > root->right->data) 
        return leftRotate(root); 

    // Left Right Case 
    if (balance > 1 && data > root->left->data) 
    { 
        root->left = leftRotate(root->left); 
        return rightRotate(root); 
    } 

    // Right Left Case 
    if (balance < -1 && data < root->right->data) 
    { 
        root->right = rightRotate(root->right); 
        return leftRotate(root); 
    } 

    return root; 
} 

int main() {
    struct node *root = NULL;

    int arr[] = { 5, 7, 2, 4, 6 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); 

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        root = insert(root, arr[i]);

    printf("BST Pre-order:\n");
    pre_order(root);

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
       root = AVLbalance(root, arr[j]);
        
    printf("\nBalanced (AVL) Pre-order:\n");
    pre_order(root);

    return 0;
}
```

After trying for hours, I cannot tell if the tree is balancing itself when being called for. Is there a logical error? Program compiles without any warning or errors. HELP!

Comment: Can you give us an example of something you've tried, what you expected, and what you got instead?

Comment: To check the tree structure, consider coding an output function that clearly describes the tree structure.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is you rely on `nn->height` to balance the tree but do not update the node heights when you insert new nodes.

You could modify the insertion function this way:

```
struct node *insert(struct node *root, int data) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return new_node(data);
    else {
        if (data < root->data)
            root->left = insert(root->left, data);
        if (data > root->data)
            root->right = insert(root->right, data);
        root->height = max(height(root->left), height(root->right)) + 1;
        return root;
    }
}
```

But this would not suffice: the function `AVLbalance` only handles the root node of the tree so rebalancing the tree after inserting all values does not work.

You should rebalance the subtree in the `insert` function when you detect an imbalance, ie when inserting `data` in a subtree increases the height of the subtree beyond the length of the other subtree + 1.  Keeping the height of each node is overkill for this. A single bit per subtree indicating it is already higher than its sibling should suffice to detect the need for rebalancing in `insert` and keep the tree balanced at all times.

Here is a naive implementation of the `insert` function that rebalances the tree upon insertion:

```
struct node *insert(struct node *root, int data) 
{ 
    if (root == NULL) 
        return new_node(data); 
  
    if (data < root->data) 
        root->left  = insert(root->left, data); 
    else if (data > root->data) 
        root->right = insert(root->right, data); 
    else
        return root; 
  
    root->height = 1 + max(height(root->left), 
                           height(root->right)); 
  
    // Handle 4 potential cases of imbalance:
    int balance = height(root->left) - height(root->right); 
    if (balance > 1) {
        if (data < root->left->data) {
            // Left Left Case 
            return rightRotate(root); 
        }
        if (data > root->left->data) {
            // Left Right Case 
            root->left = leftRotate(root->left); 
            return rightRotate(root); 
        }
    } else
    if (balance < -1) {
        if (data < root->right->data) {
            // Right Left Case 
            root->right = rightRotate(root->right); 
            return leftRotate(root); 
        } 
        if (data > root->right->data) {
            // Right Right Case 
            return leftRotate(root); 
        }
    }
    // No imbalance
    return root; 
}
```

Comment: @greybeard: does your triple negative mean you agree with my statement?

Answer (score 0):

You over-interpret *self-balancing*.

*Self-balancing search tree* means that *for client code* using "the usual interface routines" is enough to keep the tree balanced.

It does *not* mean balance is kept without coding it in the tree routines.
It is *not* enough to keep in each node information potentially instrumental in keeping/restoring balance:
balance needs to be guaranteed at the end of each modifying operation
(insert, delete, union/merge, split …).